# Drag and Drop with Congrats type message when complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have created a drag and drop for the following statements and am trying to set up a "congratulations" type thing once all the draggables have been dropped correctly.  i am going to make the whole thing fade out and display a new div congratulating - i can do that ok i just cant find the right code to check if the boxes are in the correct divs. . . Is this something i do using the jQuery or just normal javascript... does any one have a similar interaction on fiddle or codepen??

So basically:

if droppable contains draggable, draggable3, draggle4 and draggable8 AND droppable2 contains draggable2, draggable5, draggable6 and draggable7 then . . .

Thats all i need. In jQuery form lol - see below for what i was trying and what I am currently working with. :)

Here is what I am working on . . .

http://codepen.io/lbarnes/pen/hIlKG

Thanks in advance.

Apologies - in case of confusion that i havent been trying - i have used this to work individual checking but i am unsure how to make it check that all eight boxes have been dragged into the correct categories before it congratulates. . .

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert( "dropped" );
  }
});
```

So i tried this . . .

```
 $( ".draggable, .draggable2, .draggable3, .draggable4, .draggable5, .draggable6, .draggable7, .draggable8" ).draggable();
$( ".droppable, .droppable2" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert( "dropped" );
  }
});
```

js:

```
$(function() {
        /** we set the draggable class to be draggable, we add the containment which will be #boxdemo, so dropable and draggable object cant pass out of this box **/
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ 
        containment:"#boxdemo",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

    $( ".draggable2" ).draggable({ 
        containment:"#boxdemo",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

    $( ".draggable3" ).draggable({ 
        containment:"#boxdemo",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

        $( ".draggable4" ).draggable({ 
        containment:"#boxdemo",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

        $( ".draggable5" ).draggable({ 
        containment:"#boxdemo",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

        $( ".draggable6" ).draggable({ 
        containment:"#boxdemo",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

        $( ".draggable7" ).draggable({ 
        containment:"#boxdemo",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

        $( ".draggable8" ).draggable({ 
        containment:"#boxdemo",
        revert: "invalid"   
    });

    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        /** tolerance:fit means, the moveable object has to be inside the dropable object area **/
        tolerance: 'fit',
        accept: ".draggable, .draggable3, .draggable4, .draggable8",

        out: function(event, ui) {
            /** We remove the hoverClass when the moveable object is outside of the dropable object area **/
            $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hoverClass');
        },
        /** This is the drop event, when the draggable object is moved on the top of the dropable object area **/
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".droppable" ).addClass('dropClass');
        }
    });

    $( ".droppable2" ).droppable({
        /** tolerance:fit means, the moveable object has to be inside the dropable object area **/
        tolerance: 'fit',
        accept: ".draggable2, .draggable5, .draggable6, .draggable7",

        out: function(event, ui) {
            /** We remove the hoverClass when the moveable object is outside of the dropable object area **/
            $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hoverClass');
        },
        /** This is the drop event, when the draggable object is moved on the top of the dropable object area **/
        drop: function( event, ui ) {

            $( ".droppable2" ).addClass('dropClass');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Please show some research and effort before asking others to do the work for you. Think about how you want the congratulations message to work, and you'd probably find a lot of info googling it.

Comment: Tried to Google it.  As i said i am unsure as to whether i need to write it in normal javascript or jquery.$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert( "dropped" );
  }
});  this work for one but thought it was a bit messy to put this in for each individual one . . . i am not trying to get people to do my work for me, your tone is a little aggresive :(

Comment: Do you want the congratulation to be a modal? Or a popup? Or a message on the screen? If you start asking (and answering) these kinds of questions, you will find a solution rather quickly and simply. Also, you will be able to do all of it with either vanilla JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: well i am going to make the whole thing fade out and display a new div congratulating - i can do that ok i just cant find the right code to check if the boxes are in the correct divs. . . i hate putting these things in words lol!!

Comment: No worries, the new problem statement is much clearer. Just give as many details as you can in your original post, there's typically never too much information.